# How to resolve solution-level pre-build event macros when building the project on the build server?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure-pipelines, pre-build-event

I've specified a pre-build event

`$(SolutionDir)Tools\ResxConverter.CLI.exe android $(SolutionDir)$(SolutionName).Core\Resources\ $(ProjectDir)Resources\`

This works for me locally, but the build server is failing with the following:

`*Undefined*Tools/ResxConverter.CLI.exe android *Undefined**Undefined*.Core/Resources/ /Users/MyUser/myAgent/_work/9/s/MyProjectName/Resources/`

It seems the macros aren't resolving. Apparently this is because the build server builds each project individually, and the macros are only available at a solution level, but I'm not certain on that.

What do I need to do to resolve the paths to the pre-build exe on the build server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the fix was to modify the `PreBuildEvent` to refer to the `ProjectDir` rather than the `SolutionDir`, e.g.

`<PreBuildEvent>$(ProjectDir)..\Tools\ResxConverter.CLI.exe ios $(ProjectDir)..\MyProject.Core\Resources\ $(ProjectDir)Resources\</PreBuildEvent>`

This resolved the variables relative the the project, rather than the solution.